# Iterate geolocation over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, geopy

I have a dataframe that has two columns, Hospital name and Address, and I want to iterate through each address to find the latitude and longitude. My code seems to be taking the first row in the dataframe and I can't seem to select the address to find the coordinates.

```
import pandas
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
for index, item in df.iterrows():
    location = geolocator.geocode(item)
    df["Latitude"].append(location.latitude)
    df["Longitude"].append(location.longitude)
```

Here is the code I used to scrape the website. Copy and run this and you'll have the data set.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import numpy as np

r=requests.get("https://www.privatehealth.co.uk/hospitals-and-
clinics/orthopaedic-surgery/?offset=300")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
all=soup.find_all(["div"],{"class":"col-9"})
names = []
for item in all:
    d={}
    d["Hospital Name"] = item.find(["h3"],{"class":"mb6"}).text.replace("\n","")
    d["Address"] = item.find(["p"],{"class":"mb6"}).text.replace("\n","")
    names.append(d)
df=pandas.DataFrame(names)
df = df[['Hospital Name','Address']]
df
```

Currently the data looks like (one hospital example):

```
Hospital Name   |Address         
Fulwood Hospital|Preston, PR2 9SZ
```

The final output that I'm trying to achieve looks like.

```
Hospital Name   |Address         | Latitude | Longitude
Fulwood Hospital|Preston, PR2 9SZ|53.7589938|-2.7051618
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with your current and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there are a few issues here.   Using data from the URL you provided:

```
df.head()
                                Hospital Name                   Address
0                        Fortius Clinic City           London, EC4N 7BE
1  Pinehill Hospital - Ramsay Health Care UK           Hitchin, SG4 9QZ
2                  Spire Montefiore Hospital              Hove, BN3 1RD
3             Chelsea & Westminster Hospital           London, SW10 9NH
4   Nuffield Health Tunbridge Wells Hospital   Tunbridge Wells, TN2 4UL
```

**(1)** If your data frame column names really are `Hospital name` and `Address`, then you need to use `item.Address` in the call to `geocode()`.
Just using `item` will give you both `Hospital name` and `Address`.

```
for index, item in df.iterrows():
    print(f"index: {index}")
    print(f"item: {item}")
    print(f"item.Address only: {item.Address}")

# Output:
index: 0

item: Hospital Name    Fortius Clinic City 
Address              London, EC4N 7BE
Name: 0, dtype: object

item.Address only: London, EC4N 7BE
...
```

**(2)** You noted that your data frame only has two columns.  If that's true, you'll get a `KeyError` when you try to perform operations on `df["Latitude"]` and `df["Longitude"]`, because they don't exist.

**(3)** Using `apply()` on the `Address` column might be clearer than `iterrows()`.
Note that this is a stylistic point, and debatable.  (The first two points are actual errors.)

For example, using the provided URL:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()

tmp = df.head().copy()

latlon = tmp.Address.apply(lambda addr: geolocator.geocode(addr))

tmp["Latitude"] = [x.latitude for x in latlon]
tmp["Longitude"] = [x.longitude for x in latlon]
```

Output:

```
                                Hospital Name                   Address  \
0                        Fortius Clinic City           London, EC4N 7BE   
1  Pinehill Hospital - Ramsay Health Care UK           Hitchin, SG4 9QZ   
2                  Spire Montefiore Hospital              Hove, BN3 1RD   
3             Chelsea & Westminster Hospital           London, SW10 9NH   
4   Nuffield Health Tunbridge Wells Hospital   Tunbridge Wells, TN2 4UL   

    Latitude  Longitude  
0  51.507322  -0.127647  
1  51.946413  -0.279165  
2  50.840871  -0.180561  
3  51.507322  -0.127647  
4  51.131528   0.278068
```

Comment: This works to a degree, as long as the geocoder doesn't time out and do more than 1 request per second. To address this, I am adding time.sleep(2) but I am new to lambdas and realize that multiple expression are not best practice in lambda. SO, I am trying to practice converting lambda to a for loop but ran into an issue. Thoughts?? Should this be a new stackoverflow question?

Comment: Multistep operations in `apply` statements are best expressed as normal functions instead of lambdas. It's substantively different than your initial question, so I'd recommend asking in a separate post. But you might find it helpful to try building your own UDF first, this one shouldn't be too complicated and there's a lot on this topic already in pandas docs and on SO to help you along.

Comment: @andrew_reece, wonderful solution, thanks for this!